# GitHub Action build matrix: How does the $ work?

Tags: github-actions

From the [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-7):

```
runs-on: $
strategy:
  matrix:
    node: [6, 8, 10]
    os: [ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04]
steps:
- uses: actions/setup-node@v1
  with:
    version: $
```

This snippet means that the "setup-node" action is run in six different configurations (three different node versions on two different os versions).

However, I do not understand how the $ actually works. How does `runs-on` get's the values inside the `os` array filled? How does the `version` key get's the values of the `node` array filled?

How would a custom action look like that works with the build matrix option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` operator is not yet documented, but in the examples you can see it's usage. It seems to be similar to [MongoDB's `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), if you're familiar with that one. In MongoDB, and apparently here, `$` stands for "the value of the current element in the list". E.g., the documentation snippet will create six jobs, three running on Ubuntu 16.04 and three on Ubuntu 18.04.

The documentation isn't quite complete, and that the way `$` operator is used in the documentation snippet you quoted will change in the future. The snippet *should* have been:

```
runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
strategy:
  matrix:
    node: [6, 8, 10]
    os: [ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04]
steps:
- uses: actions/setup-node@v1
  with:
    version: ${{ matrix.node }}
```

Although it would be pretty simple for the GitHub Actions parser to figure out which list of strings is supposed to be assigned to the `runs-on` parameter (since 6, 8, and 10 are not valid values for `runs-on`), it cannot know what the valid values are for the `version` input of `setup-node`. (Which, BTW, has been renamed to `node-version` as of 2019-08-14, but the documentation snippet hasn't been updated yet). There is nothing in the `action.yml` config file that lists valid values of inputs, only names and descriptions.

And so since this documentation snippet wouldn't work as-is, I'm guessing that it will be updated at some point to say that `$` is the current set of selected matrix variables, and `${{ variableName }}` (e.g., `${{ matrix.node }}` or `${{ matrix.os }}`) is what you should put in the parts of your job config that use those variables.

As for the second part of your question, "How would a custom action look like that works with the build matrix option?", I think it would look like a normal action, documenting its inputs in `action.yml` (see [the `action.yml` for setup-node v1](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/blob/v1/action.yml) for an example of what this looks like). Then when you call it in your job, you'd do:

```
strategy:
  matrix:
    someVariable: [foo, bar]
steps:
- uses: my-actions/quux@v1.0
    with:
      someInput: ${{ matrix.someVariable }}
```

Comment: "Which, BTW, has been renamed to node-version" - I also thought this, but another guess I have is that the variables in the matrix are concatenated with the keys in the with block, therefore resulting in `node-version`. I have yet to try it out, I will let you know when I find something out.

Comment: Your guesses were right, just the syntax differs. There was an example along the editor on GitHub. I've updated your answer to use the correct syntax, thanks!

Comment: Actually, now that I see your edit, it looks like something in GitHub's documentation process stripped out whatever was between the `{{` and `}}` braces, leaving just the `$`. There's somewhere else where I noticed that some text (that should have been between braces) was clearly missing in the documentation. If I could remember where, I'd mention it. I don't think GitHub has an issue tracker for bugs in their documentation — at least I've never found one — or I'd report this to them as a bug.

Comment: I've reported it here: https://github.com/actions/setup-node/pull/28#issuecomment-522567135